# XML deserialization from an internal XML node

Tags: .net, xml, c++-cli, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm working on getting my .NET object serialized / deserialized. As a requirement for our XML files, the object must be inside a master node named `mycompany`. Here is an example for the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mycompany>
  <station>
    <serial>VAA008090067</serial>
  </station>
</mycompany>
```

I'm running into an issue getting this to deserialize.  I'm not aware of how to tell the serializer, "Hey, make sure you dig into the `mycompany` node before you deserialize."

Here is my current deserializtion code (not accounting for a root node):

```
Stream binaryStream = File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlSerializer xformatter = xformatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
obj = (T)xformatter->Deserialize(stream);
```

I attempted to do the following code: Create an `XmlTextStream`, read in the file header node, and the `mycompany` node, then pass the stream to the serializer

```
Stream binaryStream = File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Open);
xmlReader = gcnew XmlTextReader(binaryStream);
xmlReader.Read(); // add error checking
xmlReader.Read(); // add error checking
xformatter = gcnew XmlSerializer(T.typeid);
obj = (T)xformatter.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

The above doesn't work, throws me an `XmlElement error: Root element is missing`.

I know there is a simple solution, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: honestly i'm not sure about the whole issue, but your parsing into the xml first may be the cause of your root element missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
xformatter.Deserialize(xmlReader.ReadSubTree());
```

Comment: The following exception occured: ReadSubTree can only be called if the Reader is on an element node.  I also tried throwing a single writer->Read() before the deserialization.  Is the way I'm assigning my read from a stream incorrect?

Comment: Replace your `Read()` calls with a single call to `ReadStartElement()`

Comment: You, sir, are a scholar and a saint.